# iOS how to add not from source coding multiply viewsControllers to one ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm having some problems because I don't know how it can be done. Someone help me please.

Problem:

I have a project with a UIViewController class with created all time when I create a new project in Xcode. In this viewController, I have a xib file for designing in Xcode.

[image: start new project]

What I need is to create some views and design them in Interface Builder like this:

[image: some views]

But I need these views to be UIViewControllers, not UIViews.

The project should look like: 
[image]

So I don't know how I can do this in IB but I can do it from source code in ViewController.m

```
tab  = [[TabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mytestview" bundle:nil];
    [tab.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:tab.view];
```

But it's not my views it's a different object, and if I want to change position or size I must do it from code.  How I can do same things in Interface Builder?

Comment: Apple's docs straight up say that multiple view controllers should not be on the screen at once.  Trying to find link...

Comment: Tim, that is a good reference as people do tend to forget that was Apple' original assertion before the ipad existed. However, ipad changed that with splitViewcontroller. Further, we now have the ability to create our own container view controllers in  ios5.

Comment: However, from the limited content of the original question it looks like Rainwork shouldn't be using more than one view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider following example based on Master-Detailed Application for iPhone only.

So, add new view controller in newly created project in Xcode:
[image]

I called it NewInsideViewController. Create it without xib:
[image]

Open DetailViewController.xib. Drag View Controller and View(*) objects from library to Objects area like this (I changed view's color to LightGray):
[image]

Choose this View Controller and change its Class from UIViewController to NewInsideController at the Identity Inspector:
[image]

Assign our View(*) to NewInsideController as a view:
[image]

Now all main actions in IB finished. We need to create instance of NewInsideController in our DetailViewController. You can do it by hand, but Xcode has a nice feature - drag-n-drop ;)
[image]

I called this property as `myNewInsideController` and DetailViewController.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewInsideController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NewInsideController *myNewInsideController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@end
```

Well, now our NewInsideController ready to work and manage its view. Let's add button and action to that view in order to verify this:
[image]

Write some code in IBAction in NewInsideController.

```
- (IBAction)insideButtonClick:(id)sender {
    float rPart = arc4random()%100/100.0f;
    float gPart = arc4random()%100/100.0f;    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rPart green:gPart blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Run program.

Comment: almost exactly what I wanted. But I want it to do this with different xib files.

Comment: @George, this is impossible.. Maybe later Apple will change it, but not now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question clearly:

1. You have a parent view and controller, coming from a XIB.
2. You have placed subviews into the parent view.
3. You're wanting each subview placed into the parent view to have it's own (custom) controller, but you don't know how to add view controller's to your hierarchy (XCode will not let you drag view controllers into a view's canvas).

So, to answer the question succinctly: Let's assume you have a handful of custom UIViewController's in your project (each view controller consisting of a .h and a .m). Remember that you if you are laying these out in the context of the parent, they shouldn't have their own XIBs (you cannot nest XIBs in IB). What is important to note here is that you should only "layout" the interface in one location. If you want to have a XIB for each subview, this is not the correct approach. What you *can* (not should) do, however, is have several custom viewControllers, each connected to it's own view sitting within your parentView, and you can have the outlets of your sub view controller's set to objects in this parentView. Phew, kinda messy. The other thing you'd need to be aware of is that your parent view controller would need a reference to each of it's sub view controllers in order for you to be able to access those sub-controllers and their outlets programmatically, so for each sub view controller you add, you would also need to add an IBOutlet in your parent view controller pointing to each subviewController:

```
 ParentViewController.h
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CustomUIViewController *firstCustomController;
```

And then for example to set the background color on the view of your first custom subview/controller:

```
ParentViewController.m
[[[self firstCustomController] view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Open up your parent view controller in IB. If you look in your drawer of available objects, you'll find a *generic* UIViewController object. Drag this into your parent view controller (NOT onto it's views canvas, rather into the parent UIViewController object itself as seen in the left-column of IB builder). Select the generic view controller you've added and set it's class to your desired UIViewController subclass. Now, when your XIB loads, it will instantiate an instance of your custom view controller along with whatever you've added to it's canvas.

Finally, drag a generic UIView onto your canvas, placing it inside your existing controller's view (your screenshot already shows this as done). Right-click your custom view controller, and connect it's 'view' outlet to the view you added.

Now when you run, your custom view controller has a view that is on the screen that *is* the view of your custom controller subclass, and you didn't do any of it in code.

So now that you've done it, consider whether or not it is the best choice: Nested view controllers are messy to build (as you've seen) and aren't necessarily a good design decision: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Although iOS5 does support nested view controllers, personally I'd avoid using them. I value a best practice dictating one screen = one view controller.

[image]

Comment: If someone is asking you how to shoot himself in the leg, why would you oblige?

Comment: @Danara wouldn't. Shooting someone would be purely destructive. Imparting knowledge about *how* to do something, even if one shouldn't, is a part of gaining comprehension for the asker and the answerer. I discouraged the practice, but explained the architecture to satisfy the asker's question and curiosity.

Comment: Thanks issac for your answer, it closely what i need, but no exactly what i want. You tell me how i can use one ParentView controller with differents View and each of them has own Controller. It's good, but i need to each View has own XIB,m,h files, and in xCode i can connect them. Now i doing from soruce code like:
UIMyViewC *myC=[[UIMyViewC alloc] initWithNibName ......];
and then
[self.view addSubView:myC.view];

Comment: There isn't a way to nest XIBs into each other as you're describing. However, rather than [[self view] addSubview], what you could do is set IBOutlets for each view in your ParentView. Then, instantiate your sub-view controllers [[MyView alloc] initWithNib] and then set the your outlet view [self setMyViewOutlet:[myView view]]...

Answer (score -1):

You never, EVER, want to take views which are already under the control of a certain view controller, and make them subviews of *another* view controller's view.

View Controllers are the C part in the MVC design pattern - They are in charge of controlling a view (and its subviews). You can't take a view which is being managed by a controller, and stick it as a subview of a different controller's view - If you do that, it becomes ambigous who is responsible to manage this view.

Even though this "sticking" might be possible technically, it creates code which is hard to understand, hard to maintain, and most importantly - will cause bugs due to the unclarity of who is responsible to manage the view, and due to the fact that Apple's View/Controller framework doesn't support this.

For example: If the device is low on memory, Apple makes sure to unload views which are not currently displayed. Apple relies on the view controllers hierarchy to know when it can unload views. If you stick the view controller's view in another view controller's view, it's very likely that the view will never be unloaded even if it isn't visible.

Instead of breaking the view controller hierarchy, do one of the following:

1. Just add subviews to your view normally, either in interface builder, or in `-viewDidLoad:` to add them programatically, or (rarer) override `-loadView`.
2. Use view controller containment, either with Apple's ready-made ones (UINavigationController,UISplitViewController etc.) or with your own container view controllers (iOS>5).
3. Display view controllers modally.

The bad idea of breaking a view controller hierarchy is indeed very common and often seen in 3rd parties, probably because it's so easy and seemingly straightforward. Unfortunately this causes the aforementioned bugs :-(

I really recommend to everyone participating in this thread and comments to read Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), and watch WWDC 2011 ["View Controller Containment"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) video.

Comment: Not true. A clear example of doing this is adding any controlled view as subclass to UINavigationController (which is a view controller itself). MVC doesn't dictate that you can't somehow nest objects. Read the section titled "View Controllers Work Together to Create an App’s Interface" in the document you cite.

Comment: You can. It's not explicitly forbidden, or even explicitly advised against, in Apple docs. Maintaining MVC is the responsibility of the programmer, not Interface Builder. Of course it is useful to recommend against the practice, it's definitely bad juju. But one shouldn't confuse bad practice with "cannot do".

Comment: Also, by this rule, one couldn't very well use things like UIImagePickers, or MFMailComposers, or any other of the infinitely useful APIs published by Apple that inherit from UIViewController. They're all view controllers, and they're all generally added to an existing view (with an existing controller).

Comment: @claireware Did *you* read the part you refer to in the documentation? It refers to nesting View *Controllers*, not detaching a view out a view controller and sticking it into another view controller without maintaining the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: @isaac See my answer to claireware, in this case this isn't View Controller containment but it is displaying other View Controllers modally from another view controller - There is a well defined view controller hierarchy. What OP is asking is something else entirely - detaching a view from its controller and adding it to a controller without maintaining the hierarchy. Also, the documentation *does* explicitly state which view controllers you can nest inside which.

Comment: @Danra you are not correct. Just try to add to self.view another viewcontroller's view and see result (you can even change view's frame in order to see several views at the same time). There are different views, different controllers; each controller manages own view. All will work fine.

Comment: @beryllium you are incorrect I'm afraid. While what you wrote is correct technically, it is very bad practice to have a view hierarchy which doesn't match the view controller hierarchy. Watch the wwdc video I referenced.

Comment: @Danra From the MFMailComposerView docs: "To display the view managed by this view controller, you can use any of the standard techniques for displaying view controllers. However, the most common way to present this interface is do so modally..." Most common is not "only".

Comment: Before the original ipad came out, Apple explicitly stated in the docs that a single viewController should control a whole screen full of content. At Apple TechTalk events Apple Engineers drilled this belief home in person to developers. When ipad came out they introduced splitViewController but still maintained that best practice and their advice was to still only use one ViewController per screen full of content when not using the Apple provided container view controllers. It's clear Apple think it's bad practice to have a messy viewController hierarchy.

Comment: Now with ios5 we can create our containerViewControllers, but just because it's possible to add view controllers to views willy nilly and to not use using proper containment practice doesn't mean it's a good idea. From the limited content of the original question it looks to me that he probably shouldn't be using multiple view controllers.

Comment: @Danra - How do you think a container view controller works?  What the original poster is asking is can a container view controller have two or more visible controlled subviews. The answer is yes. Think split view controller from iPad. It's the same thing. Yes, per MVC, each subview really should be mutually exclusive entities, but MVC does not in any way dictate that only one controlled view should be visible at a time. Apple may suggest that, but that is not the same thing as MVC requiring that, which is what my "not true" statement is in response to.

Comment: @claireware It isn't what OP is asking. OP is asking about inserting a view controller's view directly into another viewcontroller's view hierarchy. See my answer for the correct alternatives.

Comment: @Danra I realize that is what he is asking. That is the definition of a container view controller. Try creating your own container view controller, you'll see how it works. OP's twist is he want's two visible controlled views in the container's view hierarchy. As I said, there is a precedence for this, the UISplitViewController. If doing what the OP is asking is not something you would want to do, that's fine. OP is asking if it is possible. The answer is yes, with some custom coding (that is, he can't d it completely with a XIB).